# Libtool library static constructor

Tags: c++, libtool

I have an autotools project using libtool. I am building a binary linked with several libtool convenience libraries. Some of these convenience libraries are not actually directly referenced by the binary, but instead they have static constructors which should be invoked when the binary runs such as:

```
__attribute__((constructor(1000)))
static void do_something() {
  ...
}
```

When I build the binary it does not link in these convenience libraries because they are seen as unneeded (the binary doesn't have any undefined symbols from these libraries). If I was using normal libraries I would just pass --whole-archive to cause the linker to link them anyways. How can I get the equivalent behavior with libtool?

Comment: have you found a solution? I have the same problem.